# Excon::Errors::Timeout: connect timeout reached

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, mandrill, excon

I am using sidekiq to send mails through Mandrill Apis. It was working all fine. But from past few days I am receiving timeout errors in sidekiq while job try to deliver mail randomly.

> Excon::Errors::Timeout: connect timeout reached

I am unable to find the actual cause of this error. I am using

- ruby '2.1.1'
- sidekiq '3.5.0'
- mandrill_mailer '1.1.0'
- mandrill-api '1.0.53'

Here is the complete error

```
2017-01-11T17:34:06.068Z 3690 TID-otkzvfo0c WARN: Excon::Errors::Timeout: connect timeout reached
2017-01-11T17:34:06.068Z 3690 TID-otkzvfo0c WARN: /home/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/excon-0.45.4/lib/excon/socket.rb:139:in `rescue in block in connect'
/home/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/mandrill-api-1.0.53/lib/mandrill.rb:35:in `call'
/home/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/mandrill-api-1.0.53/lib/mandrill/api.rb:921:in `send_template'
/home/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/mandrill_mailer-1.1.0/lib/mandrill_mailer/template_mailer.rb:121:in `deliver'
/home/app/mailers/sub_request_mailer.rb:651:in `sub_request_approved_location'
/home/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/mandrill_mailer-1.1.0/lib/mandrill_mailer/core_mailer.rb:290:in `call'
/home/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/mandrill_mailer-1.1.0/lib/mandrill_mailer/core_mailer.rb:290:in `method_missing'
```

Answer (score 0):

0.45.4 is a somewhat older version of excon (newest is 0.54.0). Updating that should be safe and would be a good next step to reduce the possible causes.

Comment: I upgraded excon version to 0.54.0 and sidekiq to 4.2.8. But nothing worked for me.

Comment: Now I am receiving 'Excon::Error::Timeout: connect_write timeout reached' after upgrading the versions of excon and sidekiq. :(

Comment: A slightly more specific error at least. Does the error happen right away, or after things have been running for some time? Also, connect errors may point to issues on mandrill's side, rather than anything you are doing wrong.